# USB Microphone does not work well on Windows 8/8.1

Tags: windows-8, usb, audio, microphone

Environment:
Windows 8.1 Pro x64

Microphone:
Audio Technica AT2005USB
Bose headset microphone

Issue:
Recording volume very low, even at maximum gain.

Google Search:
[Microsoft Post](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-hardware/windows-81-usb-microphone-volume-is-extremely-low/69e3a777-06fe-4096-9eaa-edf953ac9198?page=1&tm=1427662307055)

Like the user in the Microsoft post, the recording off of the microphone at default settings is virtually inaudible. I turned the gain to about 90% via the control panel sounds applet, and that was a bit better. The only way to here anything is to go to 100%, hold the microphone directly to my mouth, literally, and shout. At that point, yeah, I can make out what I said, albeit with distortion and breathing.

I tried two different microphones, one a Bose headset and the other a AT2005USB Audio Technical microphone. Since both microphones had the exact same issue and from two different vendors, it appears that the problem is Windows related. The answers in the Microsoft post seems to confirm that.

What I do not understand, if Microsoft really does have an issue with recording either via the microphone jack or via a USB headset,

1. Why is it that I can only find that one article?
2. Why is there not a flood of articles and complaints?
3. Why has Microsoft not fixed the issue?

Tech Smith also has no mention of this issue anywhere on their site or in the Camtasia Studio product. Their comment for best audio is to use a USB microphone, rather than a jack, and Windows 8.1.

I tried Camtasia, Windows Recorder, and Audacity. Each product yielded the same issue.

I am aware that I can purchase a multi-track recorder, such as TASCAM DP-008EX Digital Portastudio 8-track recorder, however that is overkill. I really just want to record my voice to a Power Point slide. Can that be done with Windows 8/8.1?

Addendum:
I did some more research, not to mention contact Audio Technica, and came up with these additional links:

[Link 1](http://www.highlandvoiceover.com/windows-8-and-microphone-or-adobe-audition-not-compatible-read-this/):
[Link 2](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-hardware/low-usb-microphone-recording-volume-at2020/9528f797-65c8-4033-a4d6-39995cd0d074?msgId=1824667f-7299-4511-a665-a5015166357b&page=3):
[Link 3](http://forum.audacityteam.org/viewtopic.php?f=52&t=75649):

Here is what Audio Technica told me just now:

> Unfortunately, it is a well-documented issue, not limited to Audio-Technica USB Audio Devices, that Windows 8 has lower volume with all USB Audio Devices. Due to the popularity of Audio-Technica USB microphones, any additional research might also include the Audio-Technica USB microphones, though the inherent issue is not the microphonAlthough Audio-Technica USB audio products are indeed compatible with Windows 8, it is well documented that using USB microphones (again, not limited to Audio-Technica products) with Windows 7 usually results in better performance. THIS IS BECAUSE MICROSOFT CHANGE THE DRIVER IN WINDOWS 8, AS IT COMPARES TO WINDOWS 7. As a result, you will have to turn the microphone to near maximum volume in/with Windows 8 to get comparable levels with any USB audio device.  The issue has to do with the provided Microsoft USB Audio driver, which changed the standard levels from W7 to lower levels in W8. Any potential fix would be resolved through Microsoft.
>
> As you may know, a software “Driver” is a component that an operating-system uses to provide I/O (in/out) services for interaction with an underlying device. USB Audio Drivers (in the form of a Codec) are provided by the computer’s operating-system. This USB Audio Driver is supplied by the computer’s operating system and/or the hardware (soundcard) manufacturer. This is why one can use nearly any USB audio-device with nearly any computer. Audio-Technica does not manufacture any drivers.
>
> You should that when using the microphone with Windows 7, you will not experience the issue. If that is indeed the case, then that would confirm that there is no issue with the microphone. If you try the microphone with a Windows 7 PC and the microphone does not work properly, then there would be an issue with the microphone, and Service with ATUS would be recommended. If that is the case, please visit www.audio-technica.com/service for more information.
>
> Unfortunately, there are no known drivers that will change your Windows 8 audio codec to function more like Windows 7. Your only option with any USB audio device and Windows 8 is to turn up the input/recording volume in both your operating system and the program you are using, until you get optimal results, given this Windows 8 limitation with USB audio devices. In most cases, the maximum volume in Windows 8 should suffice. If it doesn’t, however, Microsoft tech support would need to be contacted by the end user.

It seems that the portable audio recorder is the best answer. Here is yet another reason why Windows 8/8.1 sucks and Microsoft does nothing about the issue. I would not mind having Microsoft pay the cost.

Hopefully someone here has an idea for a workaround / cure.

Comment: When you mean the volume gain do you mean the Windows microphone boost: http://www.thewindowsclub.com/boost-microphone-volume-windows

Comment: @BigChris It's the "Microphone" slider, not the "Microphone Boost" slider.